# Expo EAS : How to build an app without having to start metro on my computer

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working with expo dev client and I achieve to build an app with expo dev client on my phone.

Only problem is I always need to start a metro. Can I just

Do I really need to publish on Test Flight, or can I just do a development or preview build without having to launch a local development server ?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the application through Xcode, however this will still be a development version and will need a dev server which Xcode starts after the build is complete.

To install a preview version of your application on an iPhone, the only possible way, for me at least, is to archive the application and post on TestFlight. On Android, I use eas to build a preview version of my application and i just download it on my phone.

I hope i could help you and if you have any questions, feel free to ask them!

Answer (score 0):

This is my eas.json file which I modified based on [Build APKs for Android Emulators and devices](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/apk/)

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.0.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": false,
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "development-simulator": {
      "developmentClient": false,
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Then just execute below command:

```
eas build -p android --profile preview
```

here build name i kept was **preview** but you can change it to whatever you want to keep but make sure accordingly you change inside **eas.json** file.